# How to hide lighting(like unchecking diffuse as in 2.79 ) from lamp but keeping shadows in EEVEE?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I want to add a light that cast only shadows not radiate light in eevee. In 2.79 blender internal there was a option with light, you can uncheck diffuse keeping shadows checked but in evvee how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another light in the same spot with negative power.